# Firebird connection charset

Tags: character-encoding, firebird, firebird2.5

I have problem adding a new user to Firebird database service running on localhost. Call of client library fbclient.dll method *isc_add_user* fails with error codes 335544754 (isc_error_adding_sec_record) and 335544849 (isc_malformed_string). The problem is clearly related to diacritics. This is relevant part of source code:

```cpp
bool FirebirdService::AddUser(User &user)
{
   ISC_STATUS status[20] = { 0 };
   USER_SEC_DATA data = { 0 };
   AnsiString server = (ip == L"localhost") || ip.IsEmpty() ? AnsiString("localhost") : AnsiString(ip);
   AnsiString dba_user_name = app_config.AdminUser;
   AnsiString dba_password = app_config.AdminPassword;
   AnsiString name = user.GetLogin();
   AnsiString password = user.GetPassword();
   AnsiString first_name = user.GetFirstName();
   AnsiString last_name = user.GetLastName();

   data.sec_flags = sec_dba_user_name_spec | sec_dba_password_spec | sec_first_name_spec | sec_last_name_spec;
   data.server = server.c_str();
   data.protocol = (ip == L"localhost") || ip.IsEmpty() ? sec_protocol_local : sec_protocol_tcpip;
   data.dba_user_name = dba_user_name.c_str();
   data.dba_password = dba_password.c_str();
   data.user_name = name.c_str();
   data.first_name = first_name.c_str();
   data.last_name = last_name.c_str();
   data.password = password.c_str();
   if (isc_add_user(status, &data))
   {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

This is byte content of structure field data.first_name:

[0] 'J' 74 (0x4A)

[1] 'á' -31 (0xE1)

[2] 'n' 110 (0x6E)

[3] '\0' 0 (0x00)

As soon as I change second character 'á' to 'a' the call to *isc_add_user* succeeds. How should I properly handle this kind of situation ? Is there a way to change connection charset to utf-8 or utf-16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isc_add_user` function doesn't have a connection character set, and most likely it only accepts ASCII.

Also note that the function `isc_add_user` has been deprecated since InterBase 6 (the version from which Firebird was forked in 1999/2000).

> ***Deprecated use of InterBase 5 user functions***
> The API functions `isc_add_user()`, `isc_delete_user()`, and `isc_modify_user()` are made
> obsolete by the introduction of the InterBase Services API. The new Services API
> functions are preferred over the version 5 user configuration functions in order to provide
> a consistent services mechanism, interface, and set of messages.

*(from InterBase 6 API Guide, page 219)*

It is advisable to use the service manager instead, or - Firebird 2.5 or higher - [SQL user management](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-auth-manage-users). As I am not 100% sure you can control the connection character set for the service manager, I'd suggest you use the SQL user management option instead.